# Implementation of Pohlig-Hellman unable to solve for large exponents

Tags: math, cryptography, number-theory, diffie-hellman

I'm trying to create an implementation of the [Pohlig-Hellman algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pohlig%E2%80%93Hellman_algorithm) in order to create a utility to craft / exploit backdoors in implementations of the Diffie-Hellman protocol. This project is inspired by this 2016 [white-paper](https://www.nccgroup.com/globalassets/our-research/uk/whitepapers/2016/06/how-to-backdoor-diffie-hellman.pdf) by NCC Group.

I currently have an implementation, [here](https://github.com/jinscoe123/dph/), that works for relatively small exponents – i.e. Given a linear congruence, `g^x = h (mod n)`, for some specially-crafted modulus, `n = pq`, where `p` and `q` are prime, my implementation can solve for values of `x` smaller than `min{ p, q }`.

However, if `x` is larger than the smallest prime factor of `n`, then my implementation will give an incorrect solution. I suspect that the issue may not be with my implementation of Pohlig-Hellman, itself, but with the arguments I am passing to it. All the code can be found at the link, provided above, but I'll copy the relevant code snippets, here:

```py
#
# Implementation of Pohlig-Hellman algorithm
#
# The `crt` function implements the Chinese Remainder Theorem, and the `pollard` function implements
# Pollard's Rho algorithm for discrete logarithms (see /dph/crt.py and /dph/pollard.py).
#
def pohlig(G, H, P, factors):
    g = [pow(G, divexact(P - 1, f), P) for f in factors]
    h = [pow(H, divexact(P - 1, f), P) for f in factors]

    if Config.verbose:
        x = []
        total = len(factors)
        for i, (gi, hi) in enumerate(zip(g, h), start=1):
            print('Solving discrete logarithm {}/{}...'.format(str(i).rjust(len(str(total))), total))
            result = pollard(gi, hi, P)
            x.append(result)
            print(f'x = 0x{result.digits(16)}')
    else:
        x = [pollard(gi, hi, P) for gi, hi in zip(g, h)]

    return crt(x, factors)
```

Above is my implementation of Pohlig-Hellman, and below is where I call it to exploit a backdoor in some implementation of the Diffie-Hellman protocol.

```py
def _exp(args):
    g = args.g
    h = args.h

    p_factors = list(map(mpz, args.p_factors.split(',')))
    try:
        p_factors.remove(2)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    q_factors = list(map(mpz, args.q_factors.split(',')))
    try:
        q_factors.remove(2)
    except ValueError:
        pass

    p = 2 * _product(*p_factors) + 1
    q = 2 * _product(*q_factors) + 1

    if Config.verbose:
        print(f'p = 0x{p.digits(16)}')
        print(f'q = 0x{q.digits(16)}')
        print()
        print(f'Compute the discrete logarithm modulo `p`')
        print(f'-----------------------------------------')
    px = pohlig(g % p, h % p, p, p_factors)
    if Config.verbose:
        print()
        print(f'Compute the discrete logarithm modulo `q`')
        print(f'-----------------------------------------')
    qx = pohlig(g % q, h % q, q, q_factors)
    if Config.verbose:
        print()

    x = crt([px, qx], [p, q])

    print(f'x = 0x{x.digits(16)}')
```

Here is a summary of what I am doing:

1. Choose a prime `p = 2 * prod{ p_i } + 1`, where `p_i` denotes a set of primes.
2. Choose a prime `q = 2 * prod{ q_j } + 1`, where `q_j` denotes a set of primes.
3. Inject `n = pq` as the *backdoor* modulus in some implementation of Diffie-Hellman.
4. Wait for a victim (e.g. Alice computes `A = g^a (mod n)`, and Bob computes `B = g^b (mod n)`).
5. Solve for Alice's or Bob's secret exponent, `a` or `b`, and compute their shared secret key, `K = A^b = B^a (mod n)`.

Step #5 is done by performing the Pohlig-Hellman algorithm twice to solve for `x (mod p)` and `x (mod q)`, and then the Chinese Remainder Theorem is used to solve for `x (mod n)`.

#### EDIT

The `x` that I am referring to in the description of step #5 is either Alice's secret exponent, `a`, or Bob's secret exponent, `b`, depending on which we choose to solve for, since only one is needed to compute the shared secret key, `K`.

Comment: It's not clear what `x` is in your last sentence but remember that the when solving for e.g. `b` in A^b mod n you are solving for b mod (p-1) and b mod (q-1), **not** b mod p and b mod q.

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more clear. `x` is supposed to be either `a` or `b`, depending on which is chosen to solve for.

Comment: And yes, this was my mistake, thank you! With that change, I'm now able to solve for all values of `x` less than `(p - 1)(q - 1) / 4`. Is this a limitation of the Pohlig-Hellman algorithm, or should I be able to solve for all `x` less than `n`?

Comment: Also, @President James K. Polk, if you make your comment an answer, I'll accept it, since it fixed my issue.

Comment: You have to look at the each of the primes of p-1 and q-1, which you have labeled as p_i and q_i. You are essentially performing a discrete log attack on each of these individually, then using the CRT to combine the results. Now, some of these p_i (and/or q_i) may be too large to run these attacks on. So your final x must be less than the product of all p_i and q_i that are individually small enough to run the attacks on. Actually, you can tolerate a slightly larger x, so 20 or 30 bits larger, by simply guessing these 20 or 30 extra bits and checking each guess.

Comment: Sorry, I should've mentioned that the primes, `p` and `q`, that I am choosing have smooth orders (e.g. each factor of `p - 1` and `q - 1` is, say, 32 bits or less in size). My issue now is that I can only solve for values of `x` less than `phi(n) / 4`; however, it seems to me that I should be able to solve for any `x` less than `phi(n)`, at which point I could then guess and check for slightly larger values of `x` like you said. I think this must be related to the fact that 2 is a factor of both `p - 1` and `q - 1`, which is necessary for `p` and `q` to be prime.

Comment: Yes, if all the p_i and q_i are small then you can recover the exponent for essentially the entire valid range However, this is not what Wong is proposing in his paper. Wong is talking about a property he calls Nobody-But-Us (NOBUS). In this scenario it isn't enough for the backdoor to make the discrete logarithm easy, it can only be easy for "us" but nobody else. That's the reason for using a composite modulus, to force everybody else to factor this modulus. But if you make every p_i and q_i small then anybody can easily factor the modulus. See the discussion about p_big and q_big.

Comment: Ah thank you for pointing that out. I didn't pay close enough attention to that part when reading Wong's paper the first time.